# document.referrer does not work when the iframe is reloaded

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

So I have a page which consist of an **iframe**.

Eg: Consider `htp://example.com` to be the page and `htp://test.com` as the iframe.

Now when I do `$window.location.reload` in the `htp://test.com`, while the iframe is loaded it takes the `document.referrer` as itself rather then htp://example.com.

It works fine for the first time when the main page is loaded.
**But does not work when only the iframe is reloaded.**